# Android - publish progress of String[]

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, xmlpullparser

I parse some xml and get an String[][]. And then using this I publish progress to `protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {`

But I can't send the array to this method. And am having trouble getting the values out of this. Here is the array i have.

```
String[][] myArray =  [{"there",  "there2", "there3", "there4"},
                 {"here","here2","here3"},{"hi","hi2"},
                 {"blah","blah2","blah3"}];
```

and then I do this:

```
publishProgress(dayMeals + "");
```

but I have to concatenate it with a string to send it and then when I try to get the values out of value like this I can't.

```
@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        if (values.length == 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "no data");
        }
        else {
            Log.i(TAG, values + "");

            String value0 = values[0];
            Log.i(TAG, value0);
        }
}
```

And then the log returns this

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@534cba00
[[Ljava.lang.String;@534db6c0
```

how can I get the vaules out that of the myArray?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

`String...` is essentially the same as `String[]`, and since your dataset has a type of `String[][]`, the type of progress in your case must be `String[]...`

Comment: but the function publishProgress() from xmlPullParser takes a String..., are you familiar with XmlPullParser? Is there a way around this?

Comment: @iqueqiorio, XmlPullParser doesn't have methods called publishProgress(), this is a method of AsyncTask. And when using an AsyncTask you can specify the type of progress values using generics.

Comment: right, and could you explain/ show me how to specify the type of progress value?

Comment: @iqueqiorio, You specify the types when declaring the class, e.g. public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String[], String>. Please refer to the AsyncTask documentation which describes this in detail.